# Textfield fillup data will remain as it is when i take picture using custom camera?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, camera

I have one xib that contain registration information, front and back image.

I fill all information that is ok , but when i take the image using custom camera i.e. go with my custom camera xib take picture then use this picture on another screen that is crop screen and finally use that crop image on my registration page.

My problem is that how can i do that because i fill some data in textfield then goto camera screen then goto crop screen.

so from crop screen how can i back on my registration screen without lost my fillup data and also set the crop image.

Comment: implement delegate to send data back to previous controller

Comment: shoaib thanks for replying me but i didn't get you...because here i save data after take image

Comment: but i want to go to back on my registration screen ...  how ? without lost my textfield data that i already filled.

Answer (score 0):

to dismismiss view controller use this

```
[vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{};
```

where vc is view controller you want to dismiss.